# How can I print the square roots of the first 25 off integers by using a while loop with i=i+1 instead of i=i+2

Tags: c++, while-loop

When I try to solve this problem I write the following code:

```
int x = 1;

while(x%2 != 0 && x <= 50) {      //x%2 != 0 defines odd integers and x<=50 gives the first 25
    cout << pow(x,0.5) << endl;
    x = x + 1;
}
```

This code only prints out the value of the square root of 1. So I edit the code like so:

```
int x = 1;

while(x%2 != 0 && x <= 50) {
    cout << pow(x,0.5) << endl;
    x = x + 2;
}
```

Now it prints out all the 25 odd integer square roots.

So the problem with the first code is clearly that the while loop is stopping once the square root cannot be executed (i.e. when the integer is even). It is executing the square root of 1, moving on to the integer 2, not executing the square root, and instead of then moving onto the integer 3 it is stopping. This is why the second code works: because I am adding 2 it is only ever meeting an odd integer, so always works and thus continues until x<=50.

How can I stop it from stopping and why is it doing this? I would have thought that it would register each and every integer that satisfies the condition but it is not doing this.

Comment: Put an if inside the while to check if odd or not, the while condition should be `<= 50`

Comment: Ask yourself, what is the value of the condition `x%2 != 0` when `x` is 2?

Comment: You can also iterate with `x` from `0` to `24` and compute `pow(2*x+1, 0.5)`. Such a loop is identical to your second code.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense @Cheers and hth because it is false, the entire condition is terminated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`while` executes while the condition is `true`. On the second iteration `x == 2`, so the condition `x%2 != 0` becomes `false`, consequently `x%2 != 0 && x <= 50` becomes `false` and `while` loop terminates.

You already solved *How can I stop it from stopping* part by incrementing `x` by 2, so it's unclear what you are asking here.

Comment: If you want to keep `i = i + 1` then you need to remove `x%2 != 0` from `while` condition. As suggested in the comments below the question, leave condition as `x <= 50` and add `if (x%2 != 0) continue;` as a first statement of `while` body.